# User deleted downvoted answer to reanswer with the same answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I recently came across this question: [Does $() work differently in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418231/works-differently-in-internet-explorer)

There are two answers (one is deleted, so you may not see it if you don't have the reputation). I've included a screen shot so everyone can see what I mean.

Their original answer was different then what you see, but was edited. Then deleted. Then reanswered with the edit. This seems like the user is trying to side-step the downvote on their original answer, which seems shady.

I'm not sure how to handle this, or if it even needs to be handled. I'm curious to what other think. IMO, the original answer should be restored and the repost should be removed.

> [image: Two answers of the same user, which contain the same content: one is deleted, 27 minutes old and has a score of "0", the other one is not deleted, 14 minutes old, and has a score of "-1".]

Comment: Notified the poster of this meta-question.

Comment: Flag the question.  A mod is needed to resolve the situation.  They can do the undelete/delete swap and warn the user if they feel its warranted.

Comment: If the user has a new, better answer, then why shouldn't they be able to post a separate answer with a clean slate? The person who downvoted the original answer sure isn't going to come back and un-downvote it if s/he just replaces the contents of the original.

Comment: Answer flagged for diamond attention.

Comment: @JLRishe Then the person answering the question should have taken more time to create a solid answer in the first place. They answered within 2 minutes of the question's posting. From the edit history, it's obvious they didn't read/understand the question initially, so they deserve the downvote. In the future, perhaps they will be more careful when posting hastily.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen Why do they deserve a downvote for an answer they have since deleted? Downvotes are not a _punishment_; they are a deterrent against leaving low-quality answers without deleting them afterward. This user should not have to bear a permanent badge of shame for having, once upon a time, answered a question without entirely understanding the asker's intent.

Comment: @JLRishe His un-deleted answer is of higher quality? They look ***identical*** to me.

Comment: @DonkeyKong If you look at the edit history on the deleted answer, you will see that the original answer s/he posted was radically different from its current state (the diff only shows 4 words in common, all by pure coincidence). I don't have a way of knowing when the downvote was cast, but I strongly suspect the order of events was was (1) User posted an answer (2) It was downvoted (3) User replaced the entire answer with one that better addressed the question (4) User realized s/he could start fresh by deleting the original and posting the improved answer as a new one (5) User did so.

Comment: @JLRishe Right, thanks.. In any case, that seems like a pretty questionable way to get out of a downvote (*in my opinion at least*). If that were permissible, someone could feasibly just delete every one of their answers where a downvote came *before* an upvote, then repost with an edit. It completely kills any consequence for posting a bad answer in the beginning.

Comment: @DonkeyKong As I already said, downvotes should not be intended as a permanent punishment for having once posted a bad answer. If the answer is radically changed, then I think the person has all the right to post it as a new answer. It's not like the system is going to notify its downvoters so they can come back and re-evaluate it (although I wish it would).

Comment: @JLRishe I think that encourages an *answer-before-you-think* attitude though. Downvotes can act as a deterrent to posting an initially bad or poorly thought out answer.

Comment: I apologize, I actually updated the old answer (it was originally much different). But it was still deleted... and then I added a "new" answer

Comment: If you look at the *history* of the deleted answer, it was actually completely different. I misinterpreted the question. Anyway, it was my mistake... what can I do about it now? @DonkeyKong

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen What can I do about this now?

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything. If the new answer is good, keep it. If it isn't, delete it. The fact that you posted another answer before shouldn't be a problem. In fact, you can add multiple answers to a question, so, in this case you might have posted a second answer and deleted the first. The main reason for the discussion, is that the current answer is the same as the (edited) first answer. An honest mistake I assume.

Comment: @GolezTrol Edited the old deleted answer (to what it originally was) to avoid anymore confusion

Comment: @JLRishe: *hy do they deserve a downvote for an answer they have since deleted?* Because they posted an answer that someone felt deserved a downvote. The proper conduct is to edit the answer so that it's corrected, accept that you screwed up and posted a bad answer (and thus got a downvote), and hope that your new answer earns enough upvotes to compensate. If everyone deletes a downvoted answer and posts a new one later with a correct one, it a) defeats the entire purpose of voting, b) invalidates any reputation, and c) encourages people to just post crap answers, knowing they can delete it.

Comment: @JLRishe: (continued). In addition, the poster in question is 10K+ rep, and should be aware of how the site works, the proper way to deal with an edit to an answer, and deserves the downvote for posting a wrong answer in their rush to be the FGITW. It's one thing to misunderstand the question, delete a wrong answer, and provide a new one; it's different to delete the wrong answer, and then post the same answer again with a minor change as a new answer. If the content is primarily the same, fix the wrong answer properly with an edit, and accept your responsibilities for earning a downvote..

Comment: @KenWhite _a) defeats the entire purpose of voting_ No, the purpose of voting is to weed out bad content, not to rub people's faces in the mud. _b) invalidates any reputation_ No, it just invalidates reputation on deleted content. That's how the delete feature works. _c) encourages people to just post crap answers, knowing they can delete it_ This is always true about deleted answers. Are you saying that answers shouldn't be deletable?

Comment: @KenWhite _It's one thing to misunderstand the question, delete a wrong answer, and provide a new one_ This is what the person in question did. _it's different to delete the wrong answer, and then post the same answer again with a minor change as a new answer._ This is not what the person did. As I already pointed out, a diff of the before/after shows only four words in common, and those only by pure coincidence.

Comment: @JLRishe: It has nothing to do with rubbing people's faces in it. If you don't want to get downvotes, **post the right answer in the first place**. If you're just swinging the bat hoping the pitch might end up hitting it, you're doing it wrong. If you're going to post an answer, do the reading to understand the question, ask for clarification in comments if you can't, and accept responsibility for the answer you post when you do. It's called *actually participating* in the site, rather than trying to game it for rep. Don't want to? Don't post here.

Comment: I was actually looking at this question when it happened. I was going to post about it on meta, but I don't have the 10K rep to back it up and properly explain it. Thanks for posting because it has been bugging me.

Comment: If the bottom line is that eventually a better answer shows up, then the purpose of downvoting is served.  We can't go back and assume that there is a deterrent possible to prevent crummy answers from appearing in the first place.....@JLRishe is 100% correct: even if this was frowned upon they could always delete an answer anyway without re-answering.  Deleting crummy answers is ok, and we can't get into the mind reading game here.

Comment: @Ken: _"If you don't want to get downvotes, post the right answer in the first place"_ You make it sound as if people deliberately post wrong answers and are then surprised to get downvotes. You've never accidentally posted a wrong answer? I bow to you, oh perfect being!

Comment: If someone “takes the hint” and removes a bad answer once they realise it’s bad, do they “deserve” to have the downvote as a permanent stain on their character? On a related note, it looks like I can add a comment explaining an edit, but not a deletion? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 120):

This is an unfortunate situation.

1. The author posted an incorrect answer, and got downvoted.
2. He then deleted it, changed it to a different answer (whether it's correct or not I shan't say), then undeleted it.
3. Then he realised that the old downvote was still there, and that he'd made a mistake. He deleted the existing answer and posted the new content afresh.
4. Now the meta police are downvoting his 'new' answer to oblivion.

What he should have done is post the new content as a *different* answer in the first place. That would have been absolutely fine. If your wrong answer gets downvoted, then you delete it, then you post a new, different answer instead, that's *great*! That's what we're here for.

So stop punishing the guy for originally modifying his original post. He corrected the problem with the deletion and repost. All of you spamming the new post with downvotes are not voting on the content, but on the person, and based on a misconception at that. The ones who should be reported to mods are *you*!

Comment: You are absolutely right that the downvotes were cast for the wrong reason. And probably that one should post a new answer if one writes something completely different. Though that should apply the same whether one got a net gain *or loss* in votes/rep, irrespectively. He made one *big* error though, even if he corrected it: Not preserving the old answer the way it was before his change of mind, and not adding a comment explaining *why* he deleted it, leading to this unfortunate but somewhat predictable reaction, especially with a bit of meta-advertisement. Also, let's keep either rare.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yes even if the old answer had upvotes it should have been _replaced_.

Comment: I appreciate the help @LightningRacisinObrit. It was honestly just a lapse of judgement, I've been on stack for years, I don't have any history of trying to "avoid" downvotes or anything like that. Never deleting an answer ever again :)

Answer (score 2):

If an user is doing this multiple times with malicious intent (escape from downvotes), the post ban will quickly catch up and prevent them from continuing this behavior, so these cases don't need need particular attention and can backfire if it turns out to be a honest mistake (like here - do you really think that user deserved all these hate-downvotes from the Meta effect?).

Answer (score -14):

If someone is so desperate as to take the time to do this to shave off a couple of karma points, you might as well let him get away with that. It's not strictly cheating.